# how to maintain session when browser closed in Node.js using Passort.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, passport.js

I use Passport for authentication in the Node.js app. I want to maintain session until user click on Logout button, but the session is destroyed when browser closed?
Have any body idea about this issue?

Comment: You say your using passport for authentication but what are you using for session management? Sounds like you either need to extend your session lifetime or look at token authentication.

Comment: any useful link about token authentication.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-scalable-user-mgmt)